# How to modify and customize error log for apache in linux

Tags: linux, apache, logging, httpd.conf

I try to modify the error log to show runtime duration.
I added %T/%D at the end of the LogFormat at httpd.conf

like this:

```html
<IfModule log_config_module>
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
# NOTE: "combined" and "common" are required by WHM
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%T%D %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %T/%D" combined
# access_log format can be set in WHM under 'Basic cPanel & WHM Setup'
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
</IfModule>
```

I restarted the httpd service but the change didn't take place.
At Cpanel it is specified to use the combined format.
Can someone help me  please?

Comment: Cheating answer: just change "common" to match "combined" and see what happens. I take it you're running a VPS and could theoretically ssh in if needed?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. And yes, you are correct,

Comment: OK got it. Tnx.

Comment: Silly question: are you modifying the httpd.conf that apache is actually using? I once had a machine with 3 httpd.conf's, and apache was obviously only using one.

Comment: yeah, I have only one.  Did a locate on the file before modifying. But I'll keep it in mind that it can happen. The change happened in the access log cos the data is relevent to it. I probably will educate my self a bit more on the logging system in the near puture. But for the day I got what I needed. thanks alot for the help!